# Reputation league bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

According to the [reputation league for last week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-10-16) Andy E earned 3,443. Curious to see how he did, I checked his [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e?tab=reputation), but he only he earned ~1700. I understand that the reputation leagues are a snapshot, but a difference of more than 2X seems a lot. Was this due to voting irregularities that got rolled back, or is this a genuine bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Whenever a moderator recalculates a user's reputation, a rep-league recalc is automatically triggered as well. But we had missed the case when users recalculate their *own* reputation.

In this case, Andy E recalculated his own reputation, resulting in a big rep boost, which was then mistaken as genuinely earned reputation by the leagues.